# Stop LwjglCanvas on JFrame close

Tags: java, swing, libgdx

I know this question has been asked a few times but I still didn't succeed to solve my problem :

I have a JFrame, inside the window, I have a JTabbedPane, and some tabs are a LwjglCanvas.
So i had tabs like this :

```
LwjglCanvas canvas = new LwjglCanvas(new Game(), true);
tabbedPane.addTab("127.0.0.1:6006", canvas.getCanvas());
```

But when I close the window, the whole thing freeze, I'm aware of swing deadlock and the need to call stop() on the canvas.
So i have this :

```
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
    canvas.stop();
}
```

But it still doens't work ... I can use canvas.stop() to stop it anytime while it's running, but if I do it when I close the JFrame, freeze ...

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think lwjgl and jpane's play nicely.. i could be wrong

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  You might want to change `canvas.stop();` to `System.out.println(arg0); canvas.stop();` to check the method is being called (or use a debugger to do the same).

Comment: I tried using sysout, the method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, not ideal, but I'm using this :

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run () {
            Runtime.getRuntime().halt(0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but it could help anyway. I tried @badoualy' s answer but it did not work for me. 
What worked for me is the following:

```
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    canvas.stop();
    frame.dispose(); // <=== adding this works
}
```